# How to email the contact form in a wordpress page without using php

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, email, contact-form

I have created a contact form through Wordpress. As of now, I am using a `mailto` tag, but it opens my Outlook every time. I want to send the contact form to the required email without any client-side action. For that, I planned to use a PHP script by using a plugin like PHP-Execute.

But, my boss is saying that I should avoid using a PHP script as it has bad security implications. Does anybody know what else can I use to send the contact form to my email that does not involves PHP scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is impossible. If you want to avoid `mailto:`, then you must use server-side technology. Because you are using Wordpress, the obvious choice here is PHP.

Your boss's argument makes no sense. Yes, server-side technology has risks. But that's an argument against using Wordpress or even having a website at all. It is not an argument against turning a form submission into an email on an existing Wordpress site.

There are plenty of good contact-form plugins. Use one of those and always keep it updated.